# FileVersion Output is null

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

any idea why I get nothing back on the below? The file is there on the server I query and if I do it locally it works fine in getting the file version.

```
$computer = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\servers1.txt

foreach ($server in $computer){

$path = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'SysMgmtHp'" -ComputerName $server | select pathname

(Get-Command $path).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(Get-Command $path.pathname).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
```

When you use `| select pathname` that is essentially creating a new object with a `pathname` property.  You can see this by feeding the output to `Get-Member` which gives you type info and a list of type members e.g.:

```
PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'Spooler'" | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_Service

Name                    MemberType    Definition
----                    ----------    ----------
PSComputerName          AliasProperty PSComputerName = __SERVER
...
```

versus

```
PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'Spooler'" | select pathname| Get-Member


   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
pathname    NoteProperty System.String pathname=C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe
```

All that said, you're getting the path of the service on the remote computer and then checking the version on your local computer. If you can enable remoting on the server, you could do this:

```
Invoke-Command $server { $path = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'SysMgmtHp'").PathName; (Get-Command $path).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion }
```

This will get the file version of the service binary on the remote computer.

Comment: thanks for that Keith. It is still not showing anything unfortunately though.

Comment: Run `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'SysMgmtHp'" -ComputerName $server | select pathname | fl *`.  What information does it show? That is, is the path valid. BTW you do know that you're getting a path for the service on the remote computer and then checking the version of the local copy of that service, right?

Comment: ....ahh...flip - am I checking the version on the local copy?! darn it! - I wanted to just get that path and then use the path to determine the version on the remote computer....thats the problem then! As the local computer does not have the service but the remote services do..any idea how I get the remote server to use its remote path it found and determine the fileversion of the exe?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the output of `$path.pathname` for service named 'SysMgmtHp'?  Several services have additional arguments in .pathname property or wrapped in quotes, you may need to trim these arguments/quotes. Also, post `Get-ChildItem $path.pathname | select *` results.